# How do I create a case insensitive match in Pig?

Tags: regex, apache-pig

Let's say I have the following file, students

```
John
Mary
Bill
Joe
```

I then load my data as follows:

```
a = load 'student' as (name:chararray);
```

I'd like for the results of b to be case insensitive:

```
b = filter a by name matches ('.*john.*');
```

that is, to return one match, (John). I've tried setting the regex's mode using `'?i.*john.*'`, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: How about LOWER(Name) matches...?

Comment: Yes, LOWER(name) or UPPER(name) and then go for matches

Answer (score 5):

The reason is you forgot to close the bracket for case insensitive part.
The right syntax is `'(?i).*john.*'`

Can you try this filter stmt?

```
b = filter a by name matches '(?i).*john.*';
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an ugly way to do but you can try this -

```
.*[Jj][Oo][Hh][Nn].*
```